Pine Script - Is there a way to plot only the latest data?
For example, If I am using a ma indicator and a daily chart. I want it to only show the latest day ma value on the chart; If I am using a 1 min chart, I want it to only show the lastest 1 min value on the chart.
I have tried the code below, but clearly it is not working. Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to do it? Thanks in advance.
Delay = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow) - a, 0, 0)

plot((time >= Delay) ? LB_MISSING_17 : na, color= color.green, title = "LB First Missing Value", offset = -4)
plot((time >= Delay) ? UB_MISSING_17 : na, color= color.red, title = "UB First Missing Value", offset = -4)
plot((time >= Delay) ? (LB_MISSING_17 + UB_MISSING_17)/2 : na, color = color.aqua, title = "MB First Missing Value", offset = -4)

plot((time >= Delay) ? LB_MISSING_13 : na, color= color.green, title = "LB Second Missing Value", offset = -3)
plot((time >= Delay) ? UB_MISSING_13 : na, color= color.red, title = "UB Second Missing Value", offset = -3)
plot((time >= Delay) ? (LB_MISSING_13 + UB_MISSING_13)/2 : na, color = color.aqua, title = "MB Second Missing Value", offset = -3)

plot((time >= Delay) ? LB_MISSING_9 : na, color= color.green, title = "LB Third Missing Value", offset = -2)
plot((time >= Delay) ? UB_MISSING_9 : na, color= color.red, title = "UB Third Missing Value", offset = -2)
plot((time >= Delay) ? (LB_MISSING_9 + UB_MISSING_9)/2 : na, color = color.aqua, title = "MB Third Missing Value", offset = -2)

plot((time >= Delay) ? LB_MISSING_5 : na, color= color.green, title = "LB Fourth Missing Value", offset = -1)
plot((time >= Delay) ? UB_MISSING_5 : na, color= color.red, title = "UB Fourth Missing Value", offset = -1)
plot((time >= Delay) ? (LB_MISSING_5 + UB_MISSING_5)/2 : na, color = color.aqua, title = "MB Fourth Missing Value", offset = -1)

plot((time >= Delay) ? LB_MISSING_2 : na, color= color.green, title = "LB Fifth Missing Value")
plot((time >= Delay) ? UB_MISSING_2 : na, color= color.red, title = "UB Fifth Missing Value")
plot((time >= Delay) ? (LB_MISSING_2 + UB_MISSING_2)/2 : na, color = color.aqua, title = "MB Fifth Missing Value")


How is the shared code related to the issue described?

If I am using a ma indicator and a daily chart. I want it to only show
the latest day ma value on the chart; If I am using a 1 min chart, I
want it to only show the lastest 1 min value on the chart.

To display only the most recent value of a series, a moving average value in your example, use the show_last=1 parameter. This will limit the plot to just the last bar of the currently selected timeframe chart, or any number of bars you specify with the show_last argument.
//@version=6
indicator("last sma20 value", overlay = true)
plot(ta.sma(close, 20), show_last = 1)

